# Using maven, how to configure a war into a ear file

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Im bulding an ear, that has the war of a project inside. It happens that i need a second war place in another directory, to be copied into the same .ear.

Meaning i want my ear, to contain two war files.
One war is the war of the same project where the ear is built, the other war belongs to a different project.

How can i put my pom.xml in the proper way to make this?

thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit vague because you haven't described really what you've got so far. Reading up on [maven-ear-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html) may help you clarify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think more Maven-like to solve this problem in Maven. Every project (or module of a multi-module project) creates one artifact (WAR, EAR, JAR, ...). You do not create two artifacts from the same module or project.

If you want to create two WARs and one EAR to bundle them, you need either a multi-module project with three modules or three separate Maven projects.

Two projects/modules create the WARs, and the last one bundles them. The bundling is easy: You just need to reference the WARs as dependencies of the EAR.

Comment: yes i already have two projects. One has one module where i create a war. The other has 2 modules, one where i create a war, and other where a create the ear. what i dont understand is how to put the .war of my first project inside the ear that i will build on the second.

Comment: Reference it as dependency with groupId, artifactId, version and `<type>war</type>`.

Comment: my two projects are place in a different place, not at the same level, not at the same control version level also :;\

Comment: If you build project A with Maven (like `mvn clean install`) then you can reference it from project B (on the same computer) with the Maven coordinates (groupId, artifactId,...). If this spans multiple computers, you should have a Nexus or Artifactory server to store your built artifacts.